# Is it possible to valide an SparQL for Jena?

Tags: java, sparql, jena, jena-querybuilder

Is there any way to validate/check an SparQL query?

I'm asking for a a method simillar to `oneClass.validateSparqlQuery(expectedSparQL)`.

And not **forcing the exception "QueryException"** while creating the SparQL, this way:

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryException;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;

public class myClass {

    public static void generic(String expectedSparQL) {
        try {
            Query q = QueryFactory.create(expectedSparQL);

        } catch (QueryException qe) {
            //do something if the expectedSparQL is not correct
        }

    }

}
```

javadoc: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/index.html

Comment: What would be the difference? Either the query can be parsed correctly into a `Query` object, or it is not a valid SPARQL query.

Comment: By the way, please don't use such an old version of Jena. I'm really wondering why people still use the older versions. The latest version is 3.5.0